# Convert from 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>

Tags: c#, string

Here is my code :

```
var query = System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"c:\temp\mytext.txt")
            .Select(line => line.Split(new string[] { "   " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0]);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\temp\WriteLines.txt", query);
```

I want to convert quert to string so I can edit it , like this code for example

```
string[] res = s.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

I can use `res[0].Substring` and `res[0].PadRight` many options in text

So how can I convert my first code to become string but do same function?

Comment: Did you tried `.Select(line => line.Split(new string[] { "   " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))`?

Comment: with the first code you mean ??

Comment: Yes, try changing your code to be like mine.

Comment: error in this line
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\WriteLines.txt", query);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that your file looks like this (Like grid):

```
Text11   Text12   Text13   Text14
Text21   Text22   Text23   Text24
Text31   Text32   Text33   Text34
```

Now you want to split it by cells so:

```
var query = System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"c:\temp\mytext.txt")
                .Select(line => line.Split(new[] {"   "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).ToList();
```

Now when you writing this back to the file you should join the lines:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\temp\WriteLines.txt", query.Select(line => String.Join("   ", line)));
```

And when you want to edit cell you can use:

```
query[row][column].Substring();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add `.ToArray()` at the end :

```
    var query = System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"c:\temp\mytext.txt")
                .Select(line => line.Split(new string[] { "   " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0])
                .ToArray();
```

So you can do like `query[0].Substring` and `query[0].PadRight`.

Is that what you want?

Comment: This isn't the answer you need, check how your file saved, I gamble that the file was saved wrong. Check my answer to discover how to fix that.